# Raster Merge Tool QGIS 3.16.11

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, merge, land-cover

I am performing Raster-> Miscellaneous-> Merge tool using QGIS version 3.16.11 to merge approximately fourteen Landsat8 OLI images. These images are stacked using Bands2-7 and while create the mosaic of these images. The GDAL command output showing an error:

```
**GDAL command output:**
ERROR 6: D:/SatelliteData/Merge_data/LC08_Sindh_Mosaic2016.tif, band 1: SetColorTable() not supported for multi-sample TIFF files.
```

Any idea how we can resolve this issue. I am working on a landcover project. Can I go with the output as it is generated a raster with this error?

Here is the total log file of Merge:

```
QGIS version: 3.16.11-Hannover
QGIS code revision: 26cc1c76
Qt version: 5.15.2
GDAL version: 3.3.1
GEOS version: 3.9.1-CAPI-1.14.2
PROJ version: Rel. 8.1.1, September 1st, 2021

Processing algorithm…

Algorithm 'Merge' starting…

Input parameters:

{ 'DATA_TYPE' : 5, 'EXTRA' : '', 'INPUT' : ['D:/SatelliteData/Sindh 2016/LC08_L2SP_150042_20161024_20200905_02_T1/Stacked/LC08_L2SP_150042_20161024_20200905_02_T1_SR_Bstack_raster.tif','D:/SatelliteData/Sindh 2016/LC08_L2SP_150043_20161008_20200906_02_T1/Stacked/LC08_L2SP_150043_20161008_20200906_02_T1_SR_Bstack_raster.tif','D:/SatelliteData/Sindh 2016/LC08_L2SP_151040_20161015_20200905_02_T1/Stacked/LC08_L2SP_151040_20161015_20200905_02_T1_SR_Bstack_raster.tif','D:/SatelliteData/Sindh 2016/LC08_L2SP_151041_20161015_20200905_02_T1/Stacked/LC08_L2SP_151041_20161015_20200905_02_T1_SR_Bstack_raster.tif','D:/SatelliteData/Sindh 2016/LC08_L2SP_151042_20161015_20200905_02_T1/Stacked/LC08_L2SP_151042_20161015_20200905_02_T1_SR_Bstack_raster.tif','D:/SatelliteData/Sindh 2016/LC08_L2SP_151043_20161015_20200905_02_T1/Stacked/LC08_L2SP_151043_20161015_20200905_02_T1_SR_Bstack_raster.tif','D:/SatelliteData/Sindh 2016/LC08_L2SP_152040_20161006_20200906_02_T1/Stacked/LC08_L2SP_152040_20161006_20200906_02_T1_SR_Bstack_raster.tif','D:/SatelliteData/Sindh 2016/LC08_L2SP_152041_20161006_20200906_02_T1/Stacked/LC08_L2SP_152041_20161006_20200906_02_T1_SR_Bstack_raster.tif','D:/SatelliteData/Sindh 2016/LC08_L2SP_152042_20161006_20200906_02_T1/Stacked/LC08_L2SP_152042_20161006_20200906_02_T1_SR_Bstack_raster.tif','D:/SatelliteData/Sindh 2016/LC08_L2SP_152043_20170110_20200905_02_T1/Stacked/LC08_L2SP_152043_20170110_20200905_02_T1_SR_Bstack_raster.tif','D:/SatelliteData/Sindh 2016/LC08_L2SP_153040_20161013_20200905_02_T1/Stacked/LC08_L2SP_153040_20161013_20200905_02_T1_SR_Bstack_raster.tif','D:/SatelliteData/Sindh 2016/LC08_L2SP_153041_20161013_20200905_02_T1/Stacked/LC08_L2SP_153041_20161013_20200905_02_T1_SR_Bstack_raster.tif','D:/SatelliteData/Sindh 2016/LC08_L2SP_153042_20161013_20200905_02_T1/Stacked/LC08_L2SP_153042_20161013_20200905_02_T1_SR_Bstack_raster.tif','D:/SatelliteData/Sindh 2016/LC08_L2SP_153043_20170202_20200905_02_T1/Stacked/LC08_L2SP_153043_20170202_20200905_02_T1_SR_Bstack_Reproj.tif'], 'NODATA_INPUT' : None, 'NODATA_OUTPUT' : -1, 'OPTIONS' : '', 'OUTPUT' : 'D:/SatelliteData/Merge_data/LC08_Sindh_Mosaic2016.tif', 'PCT' : True, 'SEPARATE' : False }



GDAL command:

gdal_merge.bat -pct -a_nodata -1 -ot Float32 -of GTiff -o D:/SatelliteData/Merge_data/LC08_Sindh_Mosaic2016.tif --optfile C:/Users/WWF-Pakistan/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_IeotZk/11f0c2c0bd2848a896d227be23a53105/mergeInputFiles.txt

GDAL command output:

ERROR 6: D:/SatelliteData/Merge_data/LC08_Sindh_Mosaic2016.tif, band 1: SetColorTable() not supported for multi-sample TIFF files.
```

Comment: Using the merge tool you can only extend the geographic extents of rasters which have the same config. Do you want to sum up the bands too?

Comment: Yes I need to sum up the bands too as all these rasters have the same config

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via a script:

1- Import the modules

2- Import the rasters

3- Get their `band`:

```
band_raster_1 = ds_raster_1.GetRasterBand(1)

band_raster_n = ds_raster_n.GetRasterBand(1)
```

and so on...

4 - then sum the bands together:

```
band_merged = band_raster_1 + band_raster_2 + band_raster_3 + ... + band_raster_n
```

And it's done.